# Create table from rows of another table along with its properties

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table named `Table1`

```
Column Name     Data type    Max length  Precision   Scale   is_nullable   Primary Key
    Price        float          8         53          0       1             0
    Name         varchar      180          0          0       1             0
    Id_no        int            4         10          0       1             1
    DOB          date           3         10          0       1             0
```

I need to create another table named `Table2` where the Column Name rows of table 1 (along with the properties such as Data Type, Max Length etc.,) should be my columns of another table, like

```
Table 2
Price   Name    Id_No  DOB
```

(Please note that create table query should also take into account of the properties)

Comment: you want to create another table or just select pivoted data ?

Comment: Must the solution be exclusively in SQL? If this is a backend for a PHP/Python/Ruby/Anything script, then it would be fairly straightforward to do what you want in that language.

Comment: @WKordos I want to create a new table (Table2).. where my 1st column rows of Table 1 should be my columns of Table 2..  But of the data types as specified in the other columns of Table 1..

Comment: @Dan Sullivan: Sorry, Its exclusively in SQL..

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? PostgreSQL?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name SQL Server

Comment: @Yoshi can you post some sample data and the desired result?  It might be easier to understand your request with that info.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a copy of a table with `select into`:

```
select  *
into    NewTable
from    OldTable
```

Comment: I believe OP wants to be able to create a table whose fields are defined by the rows of OldTable. He's looking to transpose the table, not copy an existing structure.

Comment: @Andomar I dont want to create a copy.. I want to create a new table where the rows of my table1 should be the columns of my table 2

Comment: @DanSullivan Exactly!  but its just not transpose.. I just need my [column Name] field values to my columns of my table 2. But my other column field values such as Data type Maxlength should be my properties

Comment: You'd need dynamic database-specific SQL to do that.  I'd do it client-side if possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table table2
as
select * form table1;
```

Comment: Even though this is standard SQL, SQL Server does not support this syntax. They chose to implement their own syntax for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically create a SQL statement and then run that command.

```
DECLARE @dsql nvarchar(max) = N''

SELECT @dsql += QUOTENAME([Column Name]) + ' ' + 
       [Data type] + 
        + CASE WHEN [Data type] = 'varchar' 
               THEN '(' + CAST([Max length] AS nvarchar(4)) + ')' ELSE '' END + ','        
FROM Table1

SELECT @dsql = 'CREATE TABLE Table2 (' + LEFT(@dsql, LEN(@dsql) - 1) + ')'
EXEC sp_executesql @dsql
```